# Float application over full screen?

Tags: xcode, macos, spaces, fullscreen, split-view

I want to view Xcode (can go fullscreen) and the iOS simulator (can't go fullscreen) on one screen. I want Xcode to be fullscreen and the Simulator next to it.

Is there a way to either:

1. Float the simulator over fullscreen Xcode? Or:
2. Have the simulator be in split-screen with Xcode?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use the Simulator in split screen :(. However you can send feedback to [Apple](http://apple.com/feedback).